# Template specialization for variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I have two functions, which accept variadic template, and second that accepts **std::vector<std::string>**. Is it possible, to override variadic templated function without additional arguments? I tried a few things, but it didn't work.

```
template <typename ... Args>
std::string Func(std::string, Args && ...);

template <typename ArgType = std::string, typename Alloc>
std::string Func(std::string, const std::vector<ArgType, Alloc> &);

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> v;
  Func("asd", 1, 2.0f);
  Func("asd", v);
}
```

Always function with variadic template pack is called. Is the compiler really can't determine the vector specialization? Thanks

Comment: Why all that, instead of a non-template function that takes two parameters: `std::string`, and `std::vector<std::ring>`?

Comment: Obligatory [Function Templates: How Do They Work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIDEjY5ywqU) reference. (Pertinent info at 41:12, but highly recommend watching entire thing)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik cuz it gonna require converting args to string and creating a vector on a client-side code, which is not convenient for a client. But I know that I have to provide a function that accepts a vector of strings, so

Comment: Function templates cannot be partially specialised. What you are showing is not a specialisation but an overload. The variadic one is almost always a better overload so it will be chosen. The only case where the second overload is better is when you pass a *const* vector object. FYI http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rt-specialize-function

Comment: "cuz it gonna require converting args to string and creating a vector on a client-side code, which is not convenient for a client" This doesn't sound terribly convincing. Whatever function that accepts a vector of strings you provide, the client will need to do exactly the same thing to call it.

Comment: "I know that I have to provide a function that accepts a vector of strings", correct, so why not actually provide such a function, instead of a template that uses a default template parameter that doesn't even work correctly?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik because I was asked to create a function that does the same thing and can accept any type any amount of argument as well. so I want to create it under 1 name as an overload if it is possible

Comment: Yes, and an overload that simply takes a `std::vector<std::string>` as a parameter, instead of `const std::vector<ArgType, Alloc>`, and then having to cross one's fingers that a `std::vector<std::string>` will select it by overload resolution.

Comment: Note that what you have is not specialization.  You have two independent `Func` overloads.  There's no reason to make the second overload a template unless you want it to be able to accept vectors of things other than strings.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the compiler really can't determine the vector specialization?

Yes it can, but it would require a conversion to `const std::vector<ArgType, Alloc>&` so the first one that doesn't require any conversion is selected instead. If you remove the `const` part it would select the second version.

You could create a type trait to disqualify the first function if the type is some sort of `vector` though.

Example:

```cpp
template<class... Ts>
struct is_first_a_vector {
    static std::false_type test(...); // matches anything

    // this matches only if the first argument is a `vector` of some sort:
    template<template<class,class> class C, class T, class A, class... Rest>
    static auto test(C<T,A>&&, Rest&&...) ->
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<C<T,A>, std::vector<T,A>>, std::true_type>;

    static constexpr bool value =
        decltype(test(std::declval<std::remove_cvref_t<Ts>>()...))::value;
};
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
template <class...>
struct is_first_a_vector_impl : std::false_type {};

template <class T, class A, class... Ts>
struct is_first_a_vector_impl<std::vector<T, A>, Ts...> : std::true_type {};

template <class... Ts>
struct is_first_a_vector
    : is_first_a_vector_impl<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<Ts>>...> {};
```

Plus a helper that works with both type traits above:

```cpp
template<class... Ts>
inline constexpr bool is_first_a_vector_v = is_first_a_vector<Ts...>::value;
```

And here's the type trait used to enable the first function only if the first argument after the `std::string` is not a `vector` of some sort:

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<!is_first_a_vector_v<Args...>, std::string> // <-
Func(std::string, Args&&...);

template <typename ArgType = std::string, typename Alloc>
std::string Func(std::string, const std::vector<ArgType, Alloc> &);
```

[Demo using version 1](https://godbolt.org/z/Wea1vGve1) and [Demo using version 2](https://godbolt.org/z/co6qrrcxe)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the code. I'll look, but it doesn't look elegant =)

Comment: @noob_programmer You're welcome. Elegant or not is in the eye of the beholder :-) I'd say it'd a pretty straight forward use of a type trait. Perhaps the implementation of the actual type trait could be made more elegant, but the point is that once you have the type trait you can then prevent `vector` types from matching the first `Func`.